# Sonarqube server fails on start due to elasticsearch not finding nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I'm trying to start SonarQube 5.1.2 server on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4

My java version is 1.7.0

Althoug I can see in the sonar.log that the elasticsearch node is started:

```
2015.07.29 15:23:07 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438179786294] initializing ...
2015.07.29 15:23:07 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1438179786294] loaded [], sites []
2015.07.29 15:23:10 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438179786294] initialized
2015.07.29 15:23:10 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1438179786294] starting ...
2015.07.29 15:23:10 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1438179786294] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9001]}
```

it fails to start while indexing rules due to a NodeDisconnectedException:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute Bulk[249 index request(s) on index rules and type rule, 35 update request(s) on index rules and type rule]
        at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxyBulkRequestBuilder.get(ProxyBulkRequestBuilder.java:51) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxyBulkRequestBuilder.get(ProxyBulkRequestBuilder.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:86) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:62) ~[sonar-core-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:370) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:361) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:106) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.executeDeprecated(IndexSynchronizer.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:850) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:847) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
2015.07.29 15:23:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[web] is stopping
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [[sonar-1438179786294][nhSNyQyhRnWN61jc3hqFDw][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1438179786294}]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:234) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1.handleException(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$3.run(TransportService.java:323) ~[elasticsearch-1.4.4.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [sonar-1438179786294][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]][indices:data/write/bulk] disconnected
```

I've tried several combinations of values for sonar.properties but none of them seemed to work:

```
sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Des.network.host=localhost

sonar.search.host=127.0.0.1
```

I've disabled the firewall and removed the /data/es folder with no luck and searched for a similar problem but was not able to find what the problem could be apart from elasticsearch not being able to find the defined node.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Can you send the full logs please ?

Comment: If you solved your question, you can post the answer and accept it, or delete the question. We don't do "solved" in the titles here though.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time that I post a question here and not aware of the procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interest, I've finally managed to find and solve the problem. The version of JRE installed by default in RHEL 6.4 is 1.7.0 and seems that there was some kind of bug related with that version. I updated the version of the JRE to the last one (java 8) and it started just fine